# How to Calculate $x$ in $5x=12+x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to calculate $x$ with this situation?

$$5x = 12 + x$$

result = (3)

How can I calculate with simple formula?

Comment: Try to bring all terms containing x on one side.

Comment: Please read our [how to ask -page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Otherwise your question is more or less guaranteed to attract negative attention.

Answer (score 4):

> result = (3) how can i calculate with simple formula?

Rather than relying on a specific formula, it's safer to be able to do this  step by step by gathering $x$ to the same side and dividing by its coefficient:
$$\begin{align}
5x=12+x \\ \tag{subtract $x$ from both sides} \\
5x-x=12 \\ \tag{simplify the left-hand side} \\
4x=12 \\ \tag{divide both sides by $4$} \\
x=\frac{12}{4}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Great, thanks! This solve my answer

Comment: @Geme You're welcome; too bad it cost me a down vote :-/.